# Dockable DIVs with scrolling inner content

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have an app that can have a number of divs on the page.  These divs are structured like this:

**CSS**

```
.DockableWindow
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 150px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: White;
    z-index: 999999;
}

.DockableWindowContent
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 87%;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px; 
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='DockableWindow'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>button</td><td>button</td><td>button</td><td>button</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='4'>
                <div class='DockableWindowContent'>scrollable content goes in here</div></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm using JQuery to set the outerdiv as draggable and resizable.  The resizable tag is also set to resize the inner div that contains the scrollable content.

This all works fine and the windows can be dragged around and re-sized with no issues.

However, I need to be able to hit a button on a toolbar and have all the currently open windows docked to the page either horizontally or vertically.  Although the windows will be docked they can still be resized and moved around if the user chooses.

I've tried this in a variety of ways but I cannot get the inner div to resize properly when the outer div is resized and positioned.

I've tried to resize using javascript and CSS but whatever I try the inner div always overhangs the bottom of the outer div.  I've also tried using JQuery to fire the resize event to get the inner div to resize but this doesn't work.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`DockableWindowContent` doesn't have to be in `position:absolute`.

Having it in absolute take it "*out*" of your `<td>`. Maybe defining `#DockableWindow td {position:relative;}` would help... But it just seems useless.

You could change `height:87%` to `min-height:87%` too. (*note*: ie6 doesn't know what min-height is)